# Conditionally adding build extension

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-extension

Is there a way to conditionally run build plugin extensions. 
More specifically :

```
           <extensions>
                <extension>
                    <groupId>co.leantechniques</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-buildtime-extension</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.1</version>
                </extension>
            </extensions>
```

Apparently you cannot add extension in a profile for eaxample :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>someid</id>
        <build>
            EXTENSION
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

any other good solution?

Comment: You are correct, per the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) `extensions` are not one of the elements that can be modified in a profile.

Comment: but is there some other way to enable the same functionality?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I'm interested in other answers this question might get too.

Comment: Are you really talking about extensions like this http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-extensions.html or maven plugin extensions ?

Comment: @khmarbaise extensions like in the guide. Is this somehow illogical to be placed in a profile or ?